how to choose the control algorithm for tracking
I am currently trying to understand the concept of resolver to digital conversion from the web. After going through datasheets and appnotes,i concluded that companies use two algorithms for resolver to digital conversion, Viz.. Lead compensator on double integrator plant and Angle tracking converter.
The lead compensator based system has open loop TF = (k/s^2)* (s+a)/(s+b) and Angle Tracking observer has open loop TF = (k1+k2/s)*k3/s
How does one choose the control algorithms? I can see the both the implementations in place. Please explain the merits and demerits for each one

What data sheets? what companies? what reasons do they give for their choices?

Companies like analog devices, part No: AD2S83. AD implements Resolver to digital conversion with Lead Compensator. NXP app note AN1942, Resolver to digital converter is implemented using angle tracking observer.
